# Calling a method . I do not get the expected output

Tags: java

When I call  `myDrawMethod(shapetriangle)` I am expected to see string triangle printed in the console as it should call the `draw` method in Class `Triangle`. Unfortunately I do not see anything printed in the console. The code is working, no errors but also nothing printed in console.

Could I get an answer why...when calling `myDrawMethod` and passing object `shapetrinagle`, I do not get the `triangle` printed in console?

Given below is my code:

```
public class Shape {
  public void draw()
  { }
}

public class Triangle extends Shape {
  public void draw(){
      System.out.println("triangle");
  }
}

public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {}

  public void myDrawMethod(Shape shape) {
      shape.draw();
  }

  public void checkMethod(){
      Shape shapetriangle= new Triangle();
      myDrawMethod(shapetriangle);
  }

}
```

Comment: You are not calling `checkMethod()` anywhere. Add `new Application().checkMethod();` to your (empty) main method.

Comment: For better understanding, when you run a java process it will first off search for the line  public static void main(String[] args){ ... } and run whatever is in those brackets. Everything else will be ignored.

Comment: clear ! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That is because your `main()` method is empty. Programs begins execution from `public static void main(String arg[])` And since your main method is completely empty, it literally does nothing.

Put this inside main.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application application = new Application();
    application.checkMethod();
}
```

Comment: clear ! many thanks!